# Consecutive Number After 16 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

i have this code in if statement , and i think it is very big , how can i change this by short code and for infinity i.e that i want the if statement to work on two and after two by sixteen i.e 2 += 16 , forever , i know that my question might be not understandable 
but please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be reduced to a mathematical problem. What you want is to divide by 16 and see if there is no 'remainder'. The 'modulo' operator gives you this remainder. You can Google it if you want to understand. So, as others have quickly posted before me, modulo in Objective-C is done via %. So `x % 16` means: divide x by 16 and return the remainder (or: subtract 16 from x until x is smaller than 16). `x % 16` will be a number between 0 and 15. *Always*. When `x % 16` is 0, it means x is dividable by 16.

Since you want to take action when count is 2 + 16 * n, you want to subtract 2 from count first. Like so `if ( ( count - 2 ) % 16 == 0)`. Or you can do this, which is shorter but perhaps less easy to understand: `if ( count % 16 == 2 )`.

Comment: +1 as you're the only one to mention the most obvious and straightforward way: `count % 16 == 2`. Looks like the other still don't really know how to use the modulus operator...

Answer (score 5):

Take the current count and subtract 2. If the number is divisible by 16 (the remainder when you do modulo division is zero), then your statement is true.

```
if ((count - 2) % 16 == 0)
{
    _secondBall.hidden = YES;   
}
```

Comment: i still have a problem bec it goes on the count of 16 and the balls neither hidden or appears this is the code that you gave me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`if ((count - 2) % 16 == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax

```
if ((count-2) % 16 == 0)
```

Comment: @user3086038, if this is the answer that helped you most. you should accept it by clicking the little tick next to the answer